# Find Rotational Eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, rotations

What are the complex eigenvalues of the matrix $A$ that represents a rotation of $\mathbb{R}^3$ through the angle $\theta$ about a vector $u$?

I know that an eigenvalue should be $1$, and the other $2$ should be complex, where one is the conjugate of the other. I can't seem to get it however.

Comment: Can you do this in two dimensions? What are the complex eigenvalues of a typical rotation matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvalues of a plane rotation of angle $\theta$ are the eigenvalues of $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{smallmatrix}\right)$: $e^{\pm i\theta}$. So, since a rotation around $u$ with angle $\theta$ maps $u$ into itself (and therefore $u$ is an engenvector with eigenvalue $1$), its eigenvalues are $1$ and $e^{\pm i\theta}$.

Comment: But since the rotation is with respect to some arbitrary axis, wouldn't the complex eigenvalue be different? Or does it not matter. That's the part I'm confused about.

Comment: Let $e_1=\frac u{\lVert u\rVert}$, let $e_2$ be a vector with norm $1$ orthogonal to $e_1$ and let $e_3$ be a vector with norm $1$ orthogonal to both $e_1$ and $e_2$. Then the matrix of $A$ with respect to the basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ is$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&\cos\theta&\mp\sin\theta\\0&\pm\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix},$$whose eigenvalues are $1$ and $e^{\pm i\theta}$.

Comment: It doesn't matter.  As far as eigenvalues are concerned, a rotation in one plane is the same as a rotation by the same angle in another plane.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Thanks!